# What am I allowed to do according to Amazon TOS?

Tags: contract-law

I found this on [Amazon TOS](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=508088):

> ... You may not incorporate any portion of the Amazon Software into your own programs or compile any portion of it in combination with your own programs ..

Now I'm wondering [what this company is doing](http://www.indix.com/usecases/enrich/) or Google/Bing as well. There are plenty of companies who scrape data from Amazon, eBay, Etsy or news websites, Stack Overflow, etc. and do something with it (either republish or analyse or similar).

So in the case of Amazon TOS: Would indix.com be doing something legal if they put the products data into their database? How about Google?

Answer (score 1):

Data is not software.  The prohibition you quote is against incorporating the programs, apps, web pages, etc., that Amazon has developed for running an internet store into one's own programs, apps, web pages, etc.  The product listings themselves are not software.

In addition, sites that redistribute Amazon data (that is, incorporate their product listings) are almost certainly *not* doing that under the terms of service that you link to.  Those are the terms of service for customers, not business partners.  There is either a standard redistribution agreement or a specific contract in place.